# Balloons tethered a viable source of unlimited electricity?

Tags: electromagnetism

I am wondering why Electrodynamic tethers are not a perfect solution to the worlds engery problems.

The resources I have found are as follows -

[Article](http://tinyurl.com/pyvt9sl)

[Test](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/STS-75)

[Wiki on how it seems to work](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Electrodynamic_tether)

The research has been done it seems. The problem was 5 hours into the flight the tether seemed to melt. Is it possible with a little more research that this could work?

It produced 3500 volts, while I do not know how electricity is measured I believe you need amps also to calculate watts. While it does not supply this can a rough estimate be made to how much this will produce?

It has come to my attention that it was not tethered to Earth. But if it were and assuming you use a balloon to hold it up could it produce the same effect?

Comment: Without any links, actual references and/or more technical information i don't see this going anywhere.

Comment: Do you have to buy expensive blueprints from an obscure website to get to know how it works?

Comment: Balloons don't go into space.  *Think* about it.  A balloon requires some air pressure to stay afloat.

Comment: They used something to get it there :o

Comment: @Griffin: Could you have a confused recollection of  [Altaeros Balloon-lifted Wind-Power generator](http://www.scientificamerican.com/video.cfm?id=balloons-set-to-take-wind-power-to2013-05-29) altitude 350 ft? If not - we need a URL for the video you are talking about!

Comment: I tried like I went through my whole Youtube search history and found 0. I think it was in a playlist. Problem is in search history they don't show the video you watched in that play list. Also it wasn't Wind Powered. I know that for sure.

Comment: @PeterJ I would love to if I could find it.

Comment: @PeterJ update I found it 
http://tinyurl.com/pyvt9sl
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/STS-75
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Electrodynamic_tether

Comment: @Griffin, I edited the question to include the link, but at a quick glance from what I can see it was tethered to a space shuttle not the earth which changes the context of your question a lot.

Comment: @PeterJ that does change a lot :( Not nearly as cool if we can't use it

Comment: @OlinLathrop I assumed they used the balloon to carry the craft as high as it could go and then used some sort of rocket to boost from there but as PeterJ as made clear it was not tethered to earth.

Comment: @PeterJ edited the question again to regard it being used within the atmosphere.

Comment: It's a little known fact that the earth's atmosphere has a very high voltage gradient with altitude.  However, it also has an extremely high impedance, so it won't be trivial to pull much power from it. This seems more plausible for a balloon vehicle in the upper atomsphere, which would not have the kind of velocity for electrodynamic effects which a satellite would. By one means or another perhaps they got enough power to melt a thin conductor their balloon could loft.  Or perhaps they confused breakage from mechanical loading or shock (temperature issues wouldn't exactly help there).

Comment: @ChrisStratton Big words and concepts. Is this a yes or no?

Comment: @Griffin - it was posted as a comment, not an answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> **sent a balloon into space. This balloon was tethered to the ground.**

Unlikely, Space is **100 km** from the surface of the earth. The weight of 100 km of tether would exceed the lifting capacity of the balloon even if a strong enough tether material were found that was able to withstand the strain of it's own weight.

"metals like titanium, steel or aluminium alloys have breaking lengths of only **20–30 km**" - [Space elevator](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Space_elevator#Cable)

Comment: Would it be possible for it to work if it wasn't in space?

Comment: @Griffin: No, there's a limit to how high a tethered balloon can fly - due to weight of tether and other factors. But even balloons with a realistically short tether cannot generate significant electricity in the way suggested - see MikeJ's answer for details.

Comment: This isn't particularly accurate. (It's not also not an *answer*, but rather a *comment* on the question)   "Space" is a relative term - you'll encounter occasional molecules of atmosphere far above the altitude of normal low earth orbits.  Balloons can in fact get you above *most* of the atmosphere so it really depends on what the goal is.

Answer (score 1):

I have no idea where those ideas come from, but here are a few issues to consider :-

Balloons don't work in space. A balloon only experiences upward force in a medium denser than the balloon itself (ie air, usually).

A static conductor in a static magnetic field generates no electricity. Either the magnetic field or the wire must be moving or the field must be changing.

You could of course anchor the wire to a vehicle and drive the balloon through the earth's magnetic field and you would have a generator of sorts (although you wouldn't get much output), but you would need to connect to the far end of the wire to complete the circuit. OK, so you could attach a second wire to the balloon end of the first wire and drop it down to earth. The problem now is that both wires now have the same induced voltage so the voltage difference between the ends is zero.

You might want to consider the authenticity of that video.

Comment: Earth's magnetic field does wiggle and move a bit, all the time. The [magnetosphere](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Magnetosphere) is also constantly being blown around by radiation from the sun. So, finding a changing magnetic field isn't the problem with this scheme.

Comment: Mike. Side note as I said it only had to reach space then it orbited I'm assuming using some weights attached.

Comment: @Griffin - something which only "reaches space" doesn't orbit, rather it falls down again.  Orbit is the special case where it has been accelerated to such an extreme "horizontal" velocity that it falls in a circle, missing the earth.  Getting to orbital velocity requires drastically more energy than simply having a trajectory which peaks at the altitude of a practical orbit.